# There is already an openEntityframework DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I got this error at **numMedidas = numMedidas + anal.Medidas.Count();** and I cannot figure out how to solve it:
InnerException: {"There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first."}
Source: EntityFramework

This is the code:

```
     PiteloDataContext contexto = new PiteloDataContext();
        var resultados = from analisis in contexto.Analises
                         select analisis;

        if (Hospitales != null)
        {
            List<string> listaHospitales = new List<string>();
            listaHospitales = Hospitales.ToString().Split(';').ToList();
            resultados = resultados.Where(b => listaHospitales.Contains(b.Incidente.Hospital.Denominacion));               

        }

NumAnalisisASPxLabel.Text = resultados.Count().ToString();

        foreach (Pitelo.EntityClasses.Analisis anal in resultados )
        {
            **numMedidas = numMedidas + anal.Medidas.Count();**
            if ((anal.FechaHora != null) && (anal.Incidente.FechaHora != null))
            {
                sumaSegundosEntreComunicacionAnalisis = sumaSegundosEntreComunicacionAnalisis + (Convert.ToDateTime(anal.FechaHora) - Convert.ToDateTime(anal.Incidente.FechaHora));
                numElementosTomarEnCuenta++;
            }
            if ((anal.FechaHora != null) && (anal.Incidente.FechaHoraCierre!=null))
            {
                sumaSegundosEntreComunicacionAnalisisCierre = sumaSegundosEntreComunicacionAnalisisCierre + (Convert.ToDateTime(anal.Incidente.FechaHoraCierre) - Convert.ToDateTime(anal.FechaHora));
                numElementosTomarEnCuenta2++;
            }
        }
```

Any tips??

Thanks!!

Comment: Try to convert the result set to ToList(). `foreach (Pitelo.EntityClasses.Analisis anal in resultados.ToList() ) { ... } `

Comment: Eric. Thanks!!! It Solved it